# Use Euler-Lagrange equations to verify angular momentum

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

We consider a spherical pendulum, where a mass $m$ experiencing gravity, is attached to a spherical joint via a massless rod of length $b$. The position of the mass can be completely characterized by specifying the two angular coordinates $\theta$ and $\phi$. We can think of this system as a point mass constraint to move on the surface of the sphere under the influence of gravity. Then we get the Lagrangian:
$$L(\theta, \phi, \dot{\theta}, \phi)=\frac{mb^2}{2}\left(\dot{\theta}^2+\sin^2(\theta)\dot{\phi}^2\right)+mbg\cos(\theta).$$
And we have to calculate the Euler-Lagrange equations associated with $L$ and verify that angular momentum is $$p_{\phi}=mb^2\sin^2(\theta)\dot{\phi}~?$$

I have tried to find the Euler-Lagrange equations, and got:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\theta}}\right)=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta}$$
$$mb^2 \ddot{\theta}=mb^2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\dot{\phi}^2-mgb \sin(\theta)$$
$$mb^2 \ddot{\theta}=\frac{mb^2}{2}\sin(2\theta)\dot{\phi}^2-mgb \sin(\theta)$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\phi}}\right)=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi}$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}(mb^2 \sin^2(\theta) \dot{\phi})=0$$
$$mb^2( \sin^2(\theta) \ddot{\phi}+2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) \dot{\phi}\dot{\theta})=0$$
$$mb^2( \sin^2(\theta) \ddot{\phi}+\sin(2\theta) \dot{\phi}\dot{\theta})=0.$$
But how can I use this to show that  $p_{\phi}=mb^2\sin^2(\theta)\dot{\phi}$? I can not see a $p$ in my  Euler-Lagrange equations. What to do then? And what will the equations of motion be?

Comment: Are you familiar with the formula for generalized momenta? It relates back to the Lagrangian itself.

Comment: Hehe nice. I did not know that formula, but I have search it up and now I see it is very easy to fin $p_{\phi}$ and I don't need Euler-Lagrange equations for that. Thank you!! What will the equations of motion be? I study mathematics so I'm not that good to the physics part

Comment: I believe it's just the equations you get from Euler-Lagrange, right? Unless you mean that you want an explicit solution for $\theta$ and $\phi,$ which looks... completely impossible I'm afraid.

Comment: Yeah I think you are right that it must just be the same